# new pdo in abstract class

Tags: php, pdo

Hello folks this is my first question on this famous and useful site.
I'm new to PDO and object php.
I'm also french so my english isn't perfect.

Here is a simple code but it doesn't work. What's wrong with it ?

Model.php

```
require_once('config.php');

abstract class Model
{
    protected static $db = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connexion();
    }

    private function connexion()
    {
        $db_options = array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING
        );

        if(is_null(self::$db))
        {
            try
            {
                self::$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DBHOST . ';dbname=' . DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS, $db_options);
            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                die("Erreur de connexion : " . $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

homeModel.php

```
require_once('Model.php');

class HomeModel extends Model
{
    private $title;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->getTitle();
    }

    private function getTitle()
    {
        $sql = parent::$db->query("SELECT title FROM table");

        $sql->execute();

        $sql->fetchAll();

        $sql->closeCursor();
    }
}
```

---

When doing public function parent::__construct() in inherited class, I have this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting '(' in HomeModel.php on line 10

I see a constructor as a default action. So when a subclass calls a main class, I want the main class to automatically execute the action defined in the constructor.

Comment: You need to call `parent::__construct()` in the constructor of the inherited model otherwise you're not initialising your connection. Also what purpose does a public constructor serve in an abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

you need to $this->getTitle(); to a property

```
$this->title = $this->getTitle();
```

And also like mentioned invoke the parent constructor so

```
parent::__construct();
$this->title = $this->getTitle();
```

Comment: i forgot to add a semicolon did u add it?

Comment: Ok I got it.

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
  $this->getTitle();
    }

The connexion to mysql seems ok.
Why does my query have a null result ?

Comment: I can't say since i don't know anything about your database layout.